# How do I reinitialize jQuery Modules after DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, dependency-management

I am using Angular 5 and jQuery 2. After a route change the DOM has changed, but stuff like the jQuery flatpicker was not reinitialized. This makes sense, but how to force a reinitialization?

For sure, the packages should be imported on the specific places, but I must not use dependency injection. The injected external libraries are loaded directly through a script tag inside the `index.html`.

> **Problem:** How to re-initiate hard injected dependencies inside an Angular app?

#### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular 5 App</title>
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
  <app></app>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://EXTERNAL-SOURCES.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="http://EXTERNAL-SOURCES.js"></script><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

#### component.ts

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 row-item">
        <div class="form-group datepicker-item datepicker-single">
          <input
            class="flatpickr flatpickr-input form-control active"
            type="text"
            data-id="rangePreload"
            readonly="readonly"
            data-input
            data-toggle
            required
            data-msg-required="Das ist ein Pflichtfeld">
<!-- ... -->
```

**UPDATE:** The injected jQuery code is initialized by `window.load()` event. While angular does not reload the window on route changes, the jQuery code won't be neither reloaded.